# Is seamless playback guaranteed when re-arranging audio nodes?

Tags: javascript, performance, audio, web-audio-api

When I'm playing audio with `AudioBufferSourceNode`, can I add other nodes before it (Gain or Panner or possibly other nodes) **without any gaps or jumps in playback**? Is this mentioned in spec somewhere? Does anyone have any experience with this?

```
// Play audio
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = someBuffer;
source.connect(context.destination);
source.start();

// Later, when source is still playing, is this safe?
source.disconnect();
source.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);

// And removing nodes is safe too?
gain.disconnect();
source.disconnect();
source.connect(context.destination);
```

I know that I can re-arrange nodes as I wish, but my question is about re-arranging during actual playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't checked the specs, but from testing, implementations do differ anyway...

When completely disconnected Chrome and Safari will pause the playback of the AudioBufferSourceNode, while Firefox will keep it running.

```js
const ctx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
let source;
let connected = true;

btn.onclick = e => {
  btn.textContent = 'loading...';
  btn.disabled = true;
  fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Turdus_fuscater_-_Great_Thrush_XC243229.mp3')
    .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buf => ctx.decodeAudioData(buf))
    .then(audioBuf => {
      source = ctx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audioBuf;
      source.onended = e => console.log('done');
      source.connect(ctx.destination);
      btn.onclick = e => {
        source.start(0);
        btn.onclick = switchConnect;
        btn.textContent = 'switch connection';
      };
      btn.textContent = 'play';
      btn.disabled = false;
    });
};

function switchConnect() {
  if (connected)
    source.disconnect();
  else
    source.connect(ctx.destination);
  connected = !connected;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mohayonao/promise-decode-audio-data@eb4b1322113b08614634559bc12e6a8163b9cf0c/build/promise-decode-audio-data.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">fetch</button>
```

Now, even if the playback doesn't pause you could experience some clicks and pops. That's even the reason why `AudioNode.disconnect()` [has been extended to allow for a `destination` parameter](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/6), which allows us to fine tune from which destination we want to disconnect, instead of disconnecting from everywhere.

So doing this, you can simply connect your node first to the new destination, and then disconnect it from the previous. This should get rid of noticeable clicks and pops, and of webkit's pause in playback.

But, note that all browsers still don't support this option, from the ones I tested, Chrome and Firefox do, Safari doesn't. Since in non-supporting browsers calling `disconnect(destination)` will actually disconnect it from **all** its destinations, we have to handle both cases in our code.

```js
let supportFineDisconnect = false;
const ctx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
const osc = ctx.createOscillator();
const gain = ctx.createGain();

// lazy checks support for AudioNode.disconnect(destination)
try {
  osc.disconnect(osc);
} catch (e) {
  supportFineDisconnect = "maybe";
}

btn1.onclick = begin;
onchange = switchRoute;

function begin(){
  osc.connect(gain);
  gain.connect(ctx.destination);
  gain.gain.value = 1;

  osc.start(0);

  btn1.textContent = 'stop';
  btn1.onclick = e => osc.stop(0);
}

function switchRoute() {
  if (!supportFineDisconnect) { // might click
    osc.disconnect(); // disconnect from all
  }
  if (+document.querySelector('input:checked').value) {
    connectDirect();
  } else {
    connectGain();
  }
}

function connectDirect() {
  // first connect to new dest
  osc.connect(ctx.destination);
  if (supportFineDisconnect) {
    osc.disconnect(gain); // then disconnect only from gain
  }
}

function connectGain() {
  // first connect to new dest
  osc.connect(gain);
  if (supportFineDisconnect) {
    osc.disconnect(ctx.destination); // then disconnect only from main
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">start playing a 440hz osc</button>
switch: <input type="radio" checked value="0" name="switch"><label>through gain</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="switch"><label>direct</label>
```

But of course, this still won't prevent clicks or pops induced by other factors (like if a change in gain or others).